# Spring boot: better way to handle response and exceptions

Tags: java, error-handling, http, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a quite a big Spring Boot web service and I wanted a standardized and simplified way to handle responses and exceptions by following fluent API design.

So this is what I did and it works as I expected.

For handling responses, first i created an `interface` like this,

```
public interface BaseResponse {
    public short code(); //holds API specific code
    public HttpStatus httpStatus(); // holds corresponding HTTP status code
}
```

And then i have created an `enum` which implements above `BaseResponse` interface,
All the response codes are defined here.

```
public enum ResponseType implements BaseResponse {
    SUCCESS((short) 10000, HttpStatus.OK),
    INVALID_FILE_TYPE((short) 10001, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST),
    //rest...
}
```

Here's the response object (`ApiResponse`) definition,

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ApiResponse {
    //holds http status code
    @JsonProperty("httpStatus")
    private short httpStatus;

    //holds API response code
    @JsonProperty("code")
    private short code;

    //holds data return from API
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private Map<String, Object> data;

    //holds errors return from API, if error response
    @JsonProperty("error")
    private Map<String, Object> error;

    public static ErrorResponseBuilder error(ApiError err) {
        return new ErrorResponseBuilder(err);
    }

    public static SuccessResponseBuilder success() {
        return new SuccessResponseBuilder();
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public static class ErrorResponseBuilder {
        private ApiError err;
        public ErrorResponseBuilder(ApiError err) {
            this.err = err;
        }

        //returns error API response
        public ApiResponse build() {
            Map<String, Object> d = new HashMap<>();
            d.put("error", err.getMessage());
            short httpStatus = (short) err.getType().httpStatus().value();

            return new ApiResponse(
                    httpStatus,
                    err.getType().code(),
                    null,
                    d
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public static class SuccessResponseBuilder {
        private Map<String, Object> pd;
        public SuccessResponseBuilder() {
            pd = new HashMap<>();
        }

        public SuccessResponseBuilder attr(String key, Object value) {
            pd.put(key, value);
            return this;
        }

        //returns success API response
        public ApiResponse build(BaseResponse type) {
            short httpStatus = (short) type.httpStatus().value();
            return new ApiResponse(
                    httpStatus,
                    type.code(),
                    pd,
                    null
            );
        }
    }

    //this is for logging
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder()
                .append("httpStatus:").append(getHttpStatus()).append(", ")
                .append("code:").append(getCode()).append(", ")
                .append("data:").append(getData()).append(", ")
                .append("error:").append(getError())
                .toString();
    }
}
```

Then i use this object to create responses like below,

**Success response**

```
//call `@Service` method, and get result of it
String fileId = this.fileHandlerService.storeFile(file);
//create success response
ApiResponse apiRes = ApiResponse.success()
    .attr("fileId", fileId)
    .build(ResponseType.SUCCESS);
//return HTTP response with 'apiRes' in body
return ResponseEntity.status(apiRes.getHttpStatus()).body(apiRes);
```

This results in below `json` response,

```
{
    "httpStatus": 200,
    "code": 10000,
    "data": {
        "fileId": "a251cb619dc145f684b9682bcb503a5c"
    }
}
```

**Error response**

To handle exception responses, i created a `Runtime Exception` called `ApiException`. This is being used to handle every exceptional cases. For example: user-not-found, inactive-user, invalid-file-type, etc...

`ApiError` class was created for hold API error details,

```
public class ApiError {
    private BaseResponse type;
    private String message;
    private String debugMessage;
    private Exception exception;
}
```

`ApiException`

```
public class ApiException extends RuntimeException {
    private ApiError apiError;
    //boilerplate code omitted
}
```

Use this exception like this,

```
throw new ApiException(ApiError.builder()
    .type(ResponseType.INVALID_FILE_TYPE)
    .message("Invalid file, please upload ms-excel file")
    .debugMessage("expected file extension:xlsx, but found:" + fileExt)
    .build()
);
```

This results in below `json` response,

```
{
    "httpStatus": 400,
    "code": 10001,
    "error": {
        "error": "Invalid file, please upload ms-excel file"
    }
}
```

This is the mechanism used every where in the web service.

- Is this a good way to handle response ?
- How can i improve it?

Comment: All the json responses are composed of two equal named fields and a third field (named error in the error response and data in the success response) ?

Comment: @dariosicily yes, they do, in `data` field of success response, i can add objects, arrays, strings etc...

Comment: One way to avoid duplicity of maps would be build a custom serializer but `jackson-databind` package has to be added in the starting spring boot configuration, have you it in your configuration ?

Comment: there is a whole article [Error Handling for REST with Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) addressing your concern...

Answer (score 2):

As you are using `Spring Boot`, the best way to handle you response is to add a [RestControllerAdvice](https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-restcontrolleradvice/).

A few rules to follow :

1. Create custom `POJO` to represent your custom message (you did it already)
2. Return directly the response message in your controller, by setting the HttpStatus, here `2XX`. You don't have to define your own HttpStatus, `Spring Boot` provides it already
3. Intercept your exceptions in your `RestControllerAdvice`. It allows you to return the custom message you want
4. Avoid sending the full exception message to your user. Send a customized clear and simple message. Log your exception full message for internal investigations instead
5. Choose the right HttpStatus code for differents situations in your `RestControllerAdvice` :

   Parameters `null` or `value not set` : `400 => Bad request`

   Returned `value not found` (record or list empty) : `404 => Not found`

   Exception from server (database error, network error etc.) : `500 => Internal server error`

Following this, you should be able to change your code to follow those few rules.